# Login and registration in HTML5 Hybrid App?

Tags: javascript, cordova, authentication, hybrid-mobile-app, html5-apps

I am a front-end developer. I am implementing HTML5 Hybrid app with Phonegap. I have setup all these things for the App but I don't have backend knowledge but I want to first implement registration and login on my first page. I have implemented one apk and this apk working fine in my mobile, But after that, I want to implement validation. I don't know how it will possible but I am thinking about javascript for this(**Registration is possible through javascript?**).Can we register form without backend programming Like Java or Php. Right now I am not using any DataBase. Give me the idea about Login what is the best thing. As per my thinking database is necessary. I am new in Hybrid app then please suggest me solution.

Comment: I think that you are looking for something like this: https://github.com/serverless/serverless. And read this: http://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html.

Comment: @Mosh Thanks for this. I will Work on this.

Comment: I don't have idea about this concept, but will work on this. thanks again for your effort Mosh.

Comment: My pleasure :) good luck..

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript at the server side with Node.js and Framewrok Express to handle requests from your mobile device in a RESTFUL API. For signing up your users is really neccesary a database, to store credentials which they'll authenticate in this case if you want to use technologies oriented to JS one option would be MongoDB. It's also recommendable use a Framework for your mobile app like Ionic which is based in Angular.js to accelerate your development.

Here a tutorial how you can achieve authenticate with some of tools I mentioned above:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

Comment: Which IDE is best for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359590/nodemon-command-is-not-recognized-in-terminal-for-node-js-server/40359656#40359656 Could you check this link. Because nodemon is not working

Comment: @varunsharma Did you install the nodemon globally? with the command `npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: @yaa. I have installed. You can see my terminal screen shot.

Comment: I have tried all command for installing nodemon. After execute every command load same files as per my screen shot(terminal).

Answer (score 0):

There are also services like Auth0 (No affiliation but we use them for my company). Depends on how much you plan on scaling user count. If SaaS or low user count, their free plan is not bad.

I also wrote a blog on various strategies when it comes to securing APIs from an HTML 5 app Cookies vs Local Storage, etc if helpful. https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/restful-apis/Authorization-on-RESTful-APIs/